# How to call a function declared in different state from ng-click given in mainpage for logout in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module("flight", ["login", "chat", "groups", "grpApp", "userApp", "ui.router"])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
        $stateProvider
            .state("login", {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: "login.html",
                controller: "loginCtrl"
            })
            .state("chat", {
                url: "/chat/:userid/:fname/:lname/:image",
                templateUrl: "flightsearch.html",
                controller: "flightCtrl"
            })
            .state("chatGroups", {
                url: "/chatGroups/:userid/:fname/:lname/:frmCityCode/:toCityCode/:originCity/:destinationCity/:dateTime",
                templateUrl: "groups.html",
                controller: "groupsCtrl"
            })
            .state("chatPage", {
                url: "/chatPage/:userid/:fname/:lname/:origin/:destination/:groupname",
                templateUrl: "grpChat.html",
                controller: "grpChatCtrl"
            })
            .state("userPg", {
                url: "/userPg/:userfbid",
                templateUrl: "userPage.html",
                controller: "userCtrl",
                params: {
                    userData: null
                }
            })
            });
```

```html
<body style="background-color:light-grey">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color:darkblue;width:100%;margin-bottom:0px">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;height:13%;font-size:25px"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><b>Flight</b>CHAT
 </a>
            </div>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" style="float:right;color:white;font-size:20px;margin-top:10px;cursor:pointer" ng-click="facebookLogout()" ui-sref="chat"></span>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <ui-view>
    </ui-view>

</body>
```

Iam working with facebook integration in my application.Here I have to login first and then go to another state.There I have to represent logout button for every state.I have declared logout button containing function calling for logout in the page where user re-directed to after login.But where I have to declare that logout function definition.I need it in every state till end.Please help me.Below are index html code and app.js code.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: I'd say change line 37

Answer (score 0):

Is there any common controller like header, in that controllr we would like to write down the facebookLogout()  fucntion.

Because of the it would be invoke in each and every route,so it will navigate.

```
$scope.facebookLogout=function(){
// here destroy the session, which has been recently created at the time of login
}
```